# Problem downloading Firebase packages to Unity project

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, duplicates, assemblies

I am receiving the error: dusplicate precompiled assemblies with the same name are now allowed -

assets/mobiledependencyresolver/editor/google.version.dll
assets/externaldependencyresolver/editor/google.version.dll  <- these are from my memory may not be exact

When I install firebase it also installs these dependencies, which results in duplicates (Im assuming because the mobile dependency resolver has the same named dll file for Android deployment)

I have tried:

1. Renaming the files - results in compilation errors because I cant just simply rename assemblies
2. Not including the duplicate files when I import the package - results in compilation errors
3. Deleting the files - compilation errors

All of the firebase SDK components include an external dependency resolver and depend on it so Im not sure how to resolve this/why im the only one having this issue.

Comment: Firebase SDK , Facebook SDK , Admob SDK, all uses External dependencies Manager and when you import that SDK they duplicates as well with the SDK so you should make sure that you don't import duplicates, try to Force Resolve by going in  External Dependency Manger-> android -> Force resolve.

Comment: @Uzair I have tried importing without the duplicates - this results in compilation errors. I do not have the option to use the external dependency manager, I only see the mobile dependency resolver? Is it not included in unity automatically?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in [Unity's Documentation](https://docs.unity.com/mediation/en/manual/SDKInstallConfigureUnity) "The Unity Mediation package is no longer available for new installs as of December 2022". Therefore unless you need to use it **and** already have it working it might be best to remove it from the project.

In order to fix your project do the following.

1. Remove both **Assets/MobileDependencyResolver** and **Assets/ExternalDependencyManager**
2. Reimport the Firebase SDK (which imports the External Dependency Manager for Unity as part of it) following the steps discussed in the [Add Firebase Unity SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add-sdks) step of the "Add Firebase to your Unity project" guide.

From there you just need to make sure the resolver is pulling in the appropriate dependencies for your target platform. Here is a [step by step guide for running and debugging](https://github.com/firebase/level-up-with-firebase/blob/main/build-and-debug-guide.md) this process.